# Disable Rule 2.2 checker

Tags: c, misra, coverity

My shop is using Coverity 2019.3.
We have MISRA-C 2004 enabled.

I want to disable MISRA-C 2004 Rule 2.2: Source code shall only use /* ... */ comments.

The `cov-analyze` command has `disable` option, but it only shows checkers.  For example, one could use `--disable` for MISRA-CAST.

We are using Coverity 2019.3 on Windows 10, with IAR 8.4 compiler (builder).

So, how can I configure Coverity to disable MISRA-C 2004, Rule 2.2?

Comment: Enforcing rules like no `//` comments is one of the reasons why MISA usage is so out-of-date.  Hope you get a good answer.

Comment: Our build system is designed to break/stop if there are Coverity Issues.  This happens to be one "false positive" that is breaking the build.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica They are using an old (obsolete) version of MISRA only supporting C90, that's why. The current (active) MISRA version supports up to C11 and doesn't have this rule.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - MISRA C;2004 only supported C90 which did not include C++ style comments.  MISRA C:2012 permits the use of `//`

Comment: @Andrew I can see advantages of not using the latest MISRA standard, but after 10 years, time to move on.

Answer (score 0):

Coverity MISRA checking is customized using the `--misra-config` command line option, which is followed by a JSON-syntax configuration file name.  See the Synopsys article [How to analyze primary source files with MISRA checkers?](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/How-to-analyze-primary-source-files-with-MISRA-checkers)

(The fact that `MISRA_CAST` responds to `--disable` is an exception because, internally, it works quite differently than the others.)

For example, to disable rule MISRA 2004 2.2, create a file called, say, `MISRA_c2004.config` with contents:

```
{ 
  version : "2.0", 
  standard : "c2004", 
  title: "Customized MISRA 2004 Compliance", 
  deviations : [ 
    {
      deviation: "Directive 2.2",
      reason: "We allow // comments here because ... ."
    }
  ]
}
```

Ideally, the `reason` should explain why your organization has chosen to disable the rule or contain a pointer to or citation of some other document containing the rationale.  I'm not an expert on MISRA compliance, but my understanding is a MISRA auditor would want to see evidence that the decision was made with due consideration to the relevant threats to the safety of the system, not merely on a whim or for programmer convenience.  The configuration file demands a reason string in order to ensure that reason is readily available to satisfy an audit.

Then add `--misra-config MISRA_c2004.config` to the `cov-analyze` command line.

Be aware that I have **not tested** the above configuration file as I don't have access to the tool anymore.  Please comment on whether it works so I can fix this answer or delete this paragraph.

Comment: I'm not sure something like a "MISRA auditor" exists. Been a while since I was part of a project actively looking for SIL qualification, but last time I was the functional safety auditors didn't have that level of detail knowledge. They were more concerned that you documented deviations in a certain manner than what the documentation actually said. That's generally the case with functional safety in my experience... as long as you _document_ that "this product might arbitrary kill or maim nearby humans" then it's a fine product...

Comment: I read about this.  The issue is that every developer will need to modify their Coverity files on their PCs.  I was hoping for something that can be done in a script or batch file.

Comment: The MISRA configuration file does not have to be placed into the Coverity installation directory.  A script should be able to generate it wherever is convenient and pass the filename to `cov-analyze`.

Comment: Please add an example `cov-analyze` call for disabling MISRA 2.2.  I'm having issues with my attempts.  The example you linked to shows how to specify the config file.  I don't want to supply a config file to each person running the MISRA checker.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Using `cov-analyze`, I don't think it can be done without the configuration file.  However, there is another command, `cov-run-desktop`, which downloads analysis configuration from the central server (including MISRA config, I believe), and is meant for individual developer use.  Maybe that would work?

Answer (score 0):

Scott gives the mechanism for resolving your problem in Coverity.

This post (a bit too long for a comment) gives some background.

--

MISRA C:2004 (published in 2004) is aligned with ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (aka `C90`) - the C++ style `//` comments were not part of C90, and although permitted by some compilers as an extension, there were inconsistent implementations leading to known issues at the time... plus it was a language extension.

Although a *required* MISRA C:2004 Rule 2.2 was (and still is) a common subject of a deviation - the process for which requires the developer to make sure that the known problems are not experienced.

Of course, if you are using MISRA C:2004 with C99 or later, you will also need a deviation against MISRA C:2004 *required* Rule 1.1 , and understand the implications of that decision.

--

MISRA C:2012 (first published in 2012/2013) extends MISRA C to cover ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (aka `C99`) in which the C++ style `//` is now a part of the language.

As such, MISRA C:2012 does not have an equivalent guideline to MISRA C:2004 Rule 2.2... and therefore the `//` comment can be freely used without a deviation.

If possible, I would encourage a transition to MISRA C:2012 for a number of reasons... `C99` support (and hence `//` comments) is but one.

--

** *See profile for affiliation* **